# How can I find path to the file in same project?

Tags: java, maven, file, intellij-idea

I have java fx application, I migrate it from pure java project to maven and now I have a problem with path to .fxml file. As you can see below I need sample.fxml in Main.java. I tried different paths and nothing is working. Can you take a look?

[image]

Here what I have tried:

```
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("src/main/java/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/java/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/java/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("fxml/sample.fxml"));
    System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("sample.fxml"));
```

Every of these returns null.

Comment: You can go back in folders by using 2 dots (..). You should use "../sample/fxml/sample.fxml"

Comment: I wish, this is not working too. System.out.println(getClass().getResourceAsStream("../sample/fxml/sample.fxml"));
        System.out.println(getClass().getResource("../sample/fxml/sample.fxml")); returns null

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

is working when we move sample.fxml to resource folder.